# How to open a link from a rich text box

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a button that when pressed it outputs a link in a rich text box. However, the link is highlighted in blue but when I click it does not open in my browser. Here is the code(Note that "https://something.com/" represents an actual link.):

```
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project 
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "https://something.com/" + textBox1.Text;

        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `richTextBox1_LinkClicked` and its parameters should help.